# On submit form populate coupon code, then send the form

Tags: javascript, arrays, form-submit

I've made a form , which by the way, i get through this website, thanks to the authors.Here's my problem :

A form , with email address , the custom is filling his email address , then an hidden field would be submitted with a coupon populated.

I have figure the php mailer and the js for the generating coupon code.

But i can't figure how to #1 populate the code , #2 send the form with the coupon code.

I'm sure, someone has asked this question before. But i can't find a solution.

I'm a newbie , but i'm passionate.

```js
function gencode(lenght) {
  var result = "";
  var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var numbers = "0123456789"
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
};
$('#btn-submit').click(function() {
  $('#secret-code').val(gencode(8));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form name="contactform" method="post" action="formsendattacs.php" type="submit">
    <table width="450px">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" id="email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <label for="ID">DEMANDE</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <input type="hidden" name="secret-code" id="secret-code" placeholder="" maxlength="30" size="30" value="gencode" class="required">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn submit" id="btn-submit" onclick="return result(gencode);">
          <div class="">
            <span class="gencode">
              <i class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
      <div class="as-console"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

the mail i receive :

DETAIL DEMANDE DE COUPON CLIENT

Email: XXXXX@xxxx.com
ID Demande: Array

This might be a mess my coding... as i said i'm learning. 
Thanks for your help
Tony

Comment: You load jQuery twice. That is never a good idea

Comment: Also press F12 and read the console error `onclick="return result(gencode);"` is incorrect

Comment: Thanks, i'll correct these, thanks Mplungian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You load jQuery twice
2. You do `onclick="return result(gencode);"` instead of `onclick="return gencode();"` and returning false in the function to stop submission
3. forms do not have type submit
4. spelling length
5. Use the submit event instead of click
6. You cannot make a hidden field required
7. Test the user filled in anything

Here is a better version using the submit event - I have unhidden the code field to show what happens

```js
function gencode(length) {
  var result = "";
  var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var numbers = "0123456789"
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
};
$('#contactform').on("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // remove when you want to submit
  // test the value
  if ($("#email").val().trim() === "") {
    alert("Please fill in email")
    e.preventDefault(); // this one stays
    return; 
  }
  $('#secret-code').val(gencode(8));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="formsendattacs.php">
    <table width="450px">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" id="email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <label for="ID">DEMANDE</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <input name="secret-code" id="secret-code" placeholder="" maxlength="30" size="30" value="gencode" class="required">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn submit" id="btn-submit">
          <div class="">
            <span class="gencode">
     <i class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i>
    </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
      <div class="as-console"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have add the corrections you have pointed to me mplungjan, i still receive the mail , but the ID DEMANDE is still filled with "ARRAY" furthermore i got this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined"  ---     at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (formsendattacs2copy.html:51)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (VM191 jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (VM191 jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ formsendattacs2copy.html:51
dispatch @ VM191 jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ VM191 jquery.min.js:2
thx again, really appreciate your help.

Comment: As you can see it works here. If there is no trim, then it is because the `$("#email").val()` does not return a string, that can only happen if the ID is wrong or if there is more than one of the same ID

Comment: You have to implement ALL my changes

Comment: Where would "ARRAY" come from?

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Here the return i get on my mail  DETAIL DEMANDE DE COUPON CLIENT

Email: xxxx@xxxx.com
ID Demande: Array
The code is generated , but i still not receive the  coupon code on the mail. Really appreciate all the help here. I'm digging more and keep the infos right here on the console.

Comment: what i mean , to make myself more clear, since english isn't my native language is : the gencode is populated ,then i click submit but the answer through the mail itself return : ID DEMANDE " ARRAY" ; i don't get the code populated

Comment: If you get ARRAY, then you are reading it wrong on the server

Comment: Ok , i'm digging this way, Mplungjan you are a great help. I let you know with the updates.

Comment: Great Day ! i have figured it out , the php file was filled with bad stuff :  like  "$post" in small caps instead "$POST",  $secret-code = $_POST["secret-code"]; // code généré automatiquement

Email: xxxx@xxxxx.com
ID Demande: PTa6GpQu    ,                                    It was a pain , i don't know if this would help, but i was stuck for 10 days, with a limited knowledge of coding, copying and pasting code here and here, which i know is not the good way to code.  There is, as i googled, lot of people whom are looking for this template : ON SUBMIT call 2 functions , Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The code rebuild with help of mplunjan and the modifications i added

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="contactform" id="contactform" method="post" action="formsendattacs.php">
    <table width="450px">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" id="email">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <label for="coupcode">DEMANDE</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <input name="coupcode" id="coupcode" placeholder="" maxlength="30" size="30" value="gencode" type="text" class="">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn submit" id="btn-submit">
          <div class="">
            <span class="gencode">
     <i class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i>
    </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

      <script type="text/javascript">
    function gencode(length) {
  var result = "";
  var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var numbers = "0123456789"
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
};
$('#contactform').on("submit",function(e) {
  // test the value
  if ($("#email").val().trim() === "") {
    alert("Please fill in email")
    e.preventDefault(); // this one stays
    return; 
  }
  $('#coupcode').val(gencode(8));
});
</script>

    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
      <div class="as-console"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the php function which was 30% the cause of trouble, some bracket and caps weren't respected at all , i've corrected these

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "xxxxx@xxxx.xxx";
    $email_subject = "demande coupon";}

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
 
 
    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['coupcode'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}
     
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $coupcode = $_POST["coupcode"]; // code généré automatiquement


 
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
 
    $email_message = "DETAIL DEMANDE DE COUPON CLIENT\n\n";
 
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
 
 
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "ID Demande: ".clean_string($coupcode)."\n";
 
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
 
<!-- include your own success html here -->
 
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
```

Answer (score 0):

Objet   demande coupon De   xxxxx@xxxxx.com À   xxxxx@xxxx.xxx 
Date    Aujourd’hui 00:34 
DETAIL DEMANDE DE COUPON CLIENT 
Email: xxxxx@xxxx.xxx 
ID Demande: **PTa6GpQu**

The mail i've receive from the form with the coupon populated, one submit button two functions .
Hope this will be helpful for anyone.